# Python replace color below or upper specific co-ordinates

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

**Scenario**

I've one image where I want to replace one color (in range of course). It is a bed-sheet image where I want to replace the color with other but I don't want to lose the reflection effect also.(I've picked the range values manually)

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('4.png')
cv2.imshow("images",image)

boundaries = [
    ([102,116,127], [203,218,227])
]
# loop over the boundaries
for (lower, upper) in boundaries:
    # create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype = "uint8")
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype = "uint8")

    # find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply
    # the mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
    #print mask
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)


    # show the images
    cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([image, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Current Output**

[image]

I think the bed is the only problem I've facing (**that's why I wanted to replace the colors only for above bed pixels**) which is kinda having the same RGB values as the Bed-sheet(my guess). I've not found any resource where I can get how to do this. I will appreciate your guidance, and I'm totally new to this.

**UPDATE**

I have tried once again with HSV values and I'm kind of happy with the result, but how do I assign(change) the color?

[image: After converting the image to HSV]

Comment: Can you attach expected output ?

Comment: @ZdaR Actually I just want to change that color to something else say blue, but I just want the plain blue it should also consider the reflection part where it must get little faded.

Comment: @usr2564301 Umm... actually. I don't want to mask this but I found this simple to use for fidning inrange colors. But my actual motto is replace the color. Like here it's kinda light brown so I want to change it to blue or something else.

Comment: Try using HSL or HSV and only change the Hue values... you may get a similar effect with the lighting... but I think it is more complicated than that to get nicer results... you need to extract the lighting information and reproduce it with the new color... but try first with the Hue and see if you like the results. BTW, it is a bed sheet not a bed shit... (first time incorrect (1st paragraph), second time correct (last paragraph) in your question)

Comment: @api55 Thank you very much I will try with the HSL or HSV and will update the result. And hahahahahah thanks I didn't realised that spelling mistake LOL.

Comment: @api55 the correction in last paragraph was made by me, Alas I missed the former one, Indrajeet you are exposed now, LOL

Comment: You can always convert any RGB value to HSV/HSL vlaue, you can see in the documentation of OpenCV the formula that is used, and then you can assign it. The important part is just the Hue, however if you want a dark blue it will be a little bit harder, since you should also influence the other two values... you can always try to add to the other values, such that the lowest of the selected colors match this value (or any specific part of the sheet) then, add and make sure it has the correct values (inside the ranges of HSV/HSL)

Comment: @api55 so there is a way just to increase hue in an image? I didn't find that specific thing

Comment: Hue is a color which normally goes from 0 to 360 (a circle in most of the image representations) in OpenCV in CV_8U images, it is represented from 0 to 180... you can always add it directly or just set them... just remember that once it reaches 180 the next one should be 0 (since it is a circle)... so to say it will be like `hue  = (hue+1) %181`