# Python replace or change the HSV value for given RGB or Hexadecimal value

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

**Scenario**

[Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242608/python-replace-color-below-or-upper-specific-co-ordinates)

I've converted the image to HSV and I want to change the values of that in Image.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('4.png')
#cv2.imshow("images",image)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)


hsv[:,:,0] = 0 # Changes the V value

out = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([hsv, out]))

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Output**

[image: Output image]

It indeed change the color based on the V value but what If I want to specify exact color I still can't figure out the co-relation between the HSV values and my RGB or Hex color values.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On the relationship between RGB and HSV spaces, I can recommend you have a look at this [blog post](http://blogs.nature.com/onyourwavelength/2018/07/18/heuristics-for-better-figures/). This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) has a detailed description of HSV and its relationsuip to RGB space.

Most visualisation libraries in python, including matplotlib, use RGB space by default, hence you need to convert your RGB image to HSV, change HSV values as you wish, and convert it back to RGB. I do not know much about cv2 library, but when I wanted to run your example, got an error message on cv2.imshow that "If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage". Hence I suggest you use a more reliable library.

To my knowledge, the best library for such purposes is [skimage](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html). Hence a sample code can be as follows. I ran it on an image of Jupiter planet that I got from [here](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/jupapr3color-jd-170304.png).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.color import rgb2hsv, hsv2rgb
image = plt.imread('jupiter.jpg')
image_hsv = rgb2hsv(image)
image2 = hsv2rgb(image_hsv)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize = (18,6))
ax[0].imshow(image)
ax[1].imshow(image2)
ax[2].imshow(image-image2)
```

As you would see, although the difference between the original RGB image and the one converted to HSV and back to RGB is not exactly zero, the difference is negligible for practical purpose. If you want to apply any changes to the HSV values of the image, you can apply it to `image_hsv` and then convert it back to RGB. 
You can use the following code to get a feel of your HSV image:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1, figsize = (8,8))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = .4)

a = image_hsv[:,:,0]
hist, bins = np.histogram(a, bins=100, normed=True)
bin_centers = (bins[1:]+bins[:-1])*0.5
ax[0].plot(bin_centers, hist)
ax[0].set(title = 'Hue')

a = image_hsv[:,:,1]
hist, bins = np.histogram(a, bins=100, normed=True)
bin_centers = (bins[1:]+bins[:-1])*0.5
ax[1].plot(bin_centers, hist)
ax[1].set(title = 'Saturation', xlim = [0,1])

a = image_hsv[:,:,2]
hist, bins = np.histogram(a, bins=100, normed=True)
bin_centers = (bins[1:]+bins[:-1])*0.5
ax[2].plot(bin_centers, hist)
ax[2].set(title = 'Value', xlim = [0,1])
```

If you run the code for the example of Jupiter image, you'd see a concentration of hue values around 0.0, representing shades of red. We can move the value of hue to the cyan range (around 0.5) using the following code:

```
image_hsv = rgb2hsv(image)
hue = image_hsv[:,:,0]
hue = hue+0.5
my_cond = hue[:,:]>1.0
hue[my_cond] = hue[my_cond]-1.0
image_hsv[:,:,0] = hue
image2 = hsv2rgb(image_hsv)
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for late reply I was kinda busy doing some other stuff. But Thank you very much for help, I will try this and will let you know if I have any questions.